# Standard template in SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I am working on a team that have a number of developers working with SQL Server, developing stored procedures, functions etc.

I would like a consistent layout between the SQL, same header with a copyright etc. SO I need a standard template for the SQL. I know in Visual Studio it is possible to share templates.

How can I generate such a template for SQL Server Management Studio that I can share between developers?

Comment: Not an complete answer sorry - http://www.sqldev.org/sql-server-tools-general/template-explorer--changing-file-location--removing-defaults-52387.shtml

Comment: @RThomas dead link...

Answer (score 5):

This is how I do it:

- the physical location of my template is in(Win7 SQL Server Management Studio 2012):

`C:\Users\ys\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\SQL Server Management Studio\11.0\Templates\Sql`

- I created my own folder in it (`00_Mine`)
- Created a git repository
- Asked other devs to pull from it.

Comment: +1 for anything git related  :)  seriously tho, not a bad approach

Comment: My trouble with this approach is the long path one must go down just to do a git commit

Comment: @PedroRodrigues - you can use mklink

Answer (score 4):

In SQL Server Management Studio, press Ctrl-Alt-T or go to Menu, View, Template Explorer

It will list all the templates. However, from SSMS, there is no easy way to add templates to it by drag and drop, you can create new ones and put them into a folder, such as `_WORK_`.

The templates live physically in (for 2008 R2): `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\VSShell\Common7\IDE\SqlWorkbenchProjectItems\Sql`, so you can simply drop files and folders in there or push out to team members using group policy.  The templates are sorted alphabetically, hence the suggestion for `_WORK_` above.  ***Note:*** A restart of SSMS is required to pick up Template Folder changes.

Here's an article: [Using SQL Server Templates](http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/3927396/Using-SQL-Server-Templates.htm)

Comment: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\SqlWorkbenchProjectItems\Sql\Stored Procedure here

Answer (score 0):

Question to users of template functionality: do you think it will be helpful if you had a possibility to have placeholders for data like: Current database, Current User, Date/Time (something else ?), so, when you open the template these placeholders would be replaced by appropriate values. I develop an add-in and had this idea a time ago, but I do not know if someone really needs it.